# About Hall's Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph. In order to find a match in the $G$ diagram so that there are no unpaired elements in the set $A$, a necessary and sufficient condition is $|A-N(T)|\leq|B-T|$ that is  for every $T\subset B$ . How can I prove this proposition?

Definitions and propositions that I know:

Corner points of graph $G$ that are not endpoints of any edge in a map $M$ are called unpaired vertices.
The set formed by the neighbors of all vertices in $T$, $T\subset B$, is denoted by $N(T)$.

Hall Condition: Let $G=(A,B,E)$ be a two-set graph. For each $S\subset A$ set, $|S|\leq|N(S)|$ If so, $G$ is said to satisfy the Hall Condition.

I tried hard, I couldn't do it, please write if you can prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.